# How to replace lubuntu for ubuntu desktop ?

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall

I know this may sound stupid, but I was having a problem with my ubuntu, it wasn't loading.

So I was googling solutions and one of them was purging something and installing something

so I did it. The proccess took a couple hours, and it didn't work. It turns out it was something to do with my graphics card (which I fixed), but when I loaded it up, I had lubuntu.

Is there any way of reverting back to ubuntu?

Or is lubuntu better to keep? I have no idea, please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure but if you do this you'll be able to retrieve Ubuntu (under a textual console not from a graphical terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge lubuntu-desktop
```

The first line will force to re-install Ubuntu desktop and the second one will remove Lubuntu desktop. After reboot you'll be good.