# how to replace lubuntu with ubuntu in a dual booted device (windows 8 and lubuntu 13)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

is there any way to replace lubuntu with ubuntu 14.04 or 15.04 in a dual booted device (windows 8 and lubuntu 13). when i searched some answers told me to desable secure boot, but i cant see it in my bios. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go from Lubuntu to Ubuntu in place, without reinstalling: https://askubuntu.com/a/361603/456122

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to "completely" replace Lubuntu and all your files, pictures etc, here is what you could do:

Basically what you need to do is to inset an installation disk(Ubuntu 14.04 in your case) and proceed as you would if you wanted to install Ubuntu alongside windows. You need to choose the option "install Ubuntu along side windows".  At this point Lubuntu should be detected by the installation disk and you can simply choose to replace it with with Ubuntu and proceed to install.