# How do I stop a flickering screen?

Tags: screen

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday and I love it...unfortunately the screen flickers when I open anything or even move the mouse at times. Is this a problem with my computer or Ubuntu?

Comment: Which kind of video card are you using?

Comment: Gallium 0.4 on NVAA

Comment: So it seems you have a NVidia video card, maybe you can try installing their  propietary drivers for linux. Type this on a console to double-check: lspci|grep VGA

Comment: forgive my ignorance...type that where??? My playstation?(jk)

Comment: Open terminal and run the command tms mentioned and share the result by updating your question

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Alt+T to open Terminal. If you hold your (I assume you use a dual-boot with Windows) Windows button between Ctrl/fn and Alt, you can see every command for Ubuntu. You have to write it in Terminal I think, works like cmd of Windows.

Comment: Oh, by the way, your command look like that:

'lspci|grep VGA'

And the output should be like that:

'00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
'

Without the 's.

Comment: GOTCHA!!! Ok so I navigate to "Terminal" and then type "lspci|grep VGA"?

Comment: Yes, if you cannot access Terminal, just let me know. I am new to Linux/Ubuntu too.

Comment: OK, typed it in and this is what I got:
"02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C77 [GeForce 8200M G] (reva2)"...jibberish

Comment: Go to NVIDIA internet site and download Linux driver of that model.

Comment: ok, so I went on there and got lost!!! How do Iknow which drivers to install? its not very self explanatory...and I'm assuming "Unix" is Linux?

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-archive.html, http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_ia32_180.22.html, those sites might answer your questions, I am pretty busy at that moment, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If your video card driver showing `Gallium 0.4 on NVCA` then it means that you have the open source NVidia drivers installed. It would be worth trying the proprietary version from NVidia.

You mentioned in comments that the result from the command `lspci|grep` in a terminal was

> NVIDIA Corporation C77 [GeForce 8200M G]

If you installed an x64 version of linux, you can try downloading and installing this driver:

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/114719/en-us

Your card is not on the list of the "supported products", but when you navigate through the filters of the website that's the one that shows up as result.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just Installed Lubuntu since its a bit "liter". No flickering! However, I really liked Ubuntu and if you think that could help fix the problem then I'm inclined to give that a try...but Lubuntu is working just fine...fml!!!

Comment: @DavidBerna Lubuntu does not need hardware acceleration, this is probably why it worked fine.

Comment: makes sense...so should i try reinstalling Ubuntu and see if that suggestion solves the flickering screen fiasco? I guess more importantly: Which "flavor" would best fit my needs (need a good office suite for my writing and marketing needs, I need to be able to run Kodi SMOOTHLY, and I have a habit of downloading software and trying it out even if i don't need it...i have a downloading addiction thats pretty bad; just look at my phone apps...)?

Comment: Actually [you don't need to reinstall](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361598/how-to-replace-lubuntu-for-ubuntu-desktop) to go back and forth from lubuntu to regular ubuntu, so indeed you can just install the driver and try it out on your current installation.